# VueJS - Bootstrap form validation

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue, vee-validate

I have a form that would ask user to input personal information, such as Fname, Lname, cellphone, address, etc.

For address, it is broken into 6 input boxes, namely

- Street Address Line 1
- Street Address Line 2
- City
- Province
- Country
- Postal Code/ZIP

Now, the problem is that I need to make sure the user must either

1. leave all 6 fields blank

or

2. fill out all 5 fields (except Street Address Line 2 is optional)

The problem I couldnt figure out is that

1. I know how to make a < base-input > "required", but how do you make a < b-form-select > "required" ?
2. After making them required, how do I do it conditionally? I am guessing a if statement that checks if any one of the five required fields are not null, but how?

```
<template>
  <validation-observer ref="formValidator">
    <b-form role="form">
      <!-- I will skip all others input fields and show one that works with validaiton already. -->
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <b-form-group>
            <b-input-group>
              <base-input
                v-model="Cell"
                type="tel"
                pattern="[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}"
                :rules="{ required: true }"
                :placeholder="$t('Cell Phone')"
                :label="$t('Cell Phone') + '* (10 digits)'"
                ref="cellphone"
                name="cellphone"
                @focus="handleinput('cellphone')" id="cellphone"
              ></base-input>
            </b-input-group>
          </b-form-group>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
      <!-- Above is one that is working, but it is not conditional. How do I make the below three fields required conditionally? -->
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <b-form-group>
            <b-input-group>
              <base-input
                :rules="{ required: true }"
                v-model="Street1"
                :placeholder="$t('Address Line 1')"
                :label="$t('Address Line 1')"
                ref="address_line_1"
                name="address line 1"
                @focus="handleinput('address1')" id="address1"
              ></base-input>
            </b-input-group>
          </b-form-group>
        </b-col>
        <b-col>
          <div>
            <label class="form-control-label">{{ $t("Country") }}</label>
            <div class="has-label">
              <b-form-select
                v-model="address.CountryIDn"
                @change="changeCountry"
              >
                <option value="0">--{{ $t("Country") }}--</option>
                <option
                  v-for="(country, index) in countries"
                  :key="index"
                  :value="country.IDn"
                >
                  {{ country.Country }}
                </option>
              </b-form-select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </b-col>
        <b-col>
          <div>
            <label class="form-control-label">{{ $t("Province") }}</label>
            <div class="has-label">
              <b-form-select v-model="address.ProvinceIDn">
                <option value="0">--{{ $t("Province") }}--</option>
                <option
                  v-for="(province, index) in provinces"
                  :key="index"
                  :value="province.IDn"
                >
                  {{ province.Province }}
                </option>
              </b-form-select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </b-col>
    </b-form>
  </validation-observer>
</template>
```